# Adapting to Chrome disabling third-party cookies

Tags: reactjs, node.js, google-chrome, cookies

Google is restricting third-party cookies in Chrome. I have a web app that uses Node and React.

The Authentication and Authorization strategy involves using JWT and cookies with credentials. I'm not exactly sure if this type of cookies can be considered third party cookie.

I have search Google, but Im not being able to determine if I should change the Auth strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your app by enabling the following flag:

[Chrome]
chrome://flags/#test-third-party-cookie-phaseout

[Edge]
edge://flags/#test-third-party-cookie-phaseout

See: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/blog/cookie-countdown-2023oct#test